# Adobe AIR Native Extensions

Tags: air, bluetooth, air-native-extension

I have a problem with AIR Native Extensions.
For my bachelor thesis I have to create a Multiplayer-Game on tablets, where the players communicate via Bluetooth.
I have to implement my game with AIR, because it must work on all tablets(IPad, Samsung Tablets,...)
I have to use AIR Native Extension, because ActionScript has no Bluetooth API.

I have some questions concerning my topic:

1. Is it true that I have to implement the native code for my extension in C? I read that Java native Code only works for Android.
2. For a native Extension I need the native code, the ActionScript library which acts as an Interface, thats clear. But I don´t know why I need a Flex project for creating the AIR Native Extension? I just want to call the native methods from my game. I hope anybody can explain it to me.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to write native code for each individual platform. So you will need to write code in both Java (Android) and Objective-C (iOS). The extension is nothing more than a bridge to native code
2. You do not need Flex to use a Native Extension. The Native Extension should be written entirely in ActionScript with the native portion of the extension being written in the native language (Java, Objective-C, or C++, depending on platform)

You should look at the resources Adobe has provided on the subject. ANEs are not the most documented feature in the world, but there are plenty of resources available to get you started. Additionally, there are already ANEs publicly available that allow for bluetooth support. I have never tested them so I cannot vouch for their quality of effectiveness, but if you can use third-party libraries, it is probably worth giving them a look.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/air_extensions.pdf
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html

Comment: You can use third party libraries but there are linkage hacks/workarounds you have to use to get them to link properly in the ANE.

Comment: @Nabren Reread what said. I never said anything about using third party libraries in the extension. I was just asking if the asker can use them in his project for school. If he can, he should use an already-built ANE so that he doesn't have to go through the hassle of building one himself.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I thought this statement: "I have never tested them so I cannot vouch for their quality of effectiveness, but if you can use third-party libraries, it is probably worth giving them a look." meant using third-party libraries in an ANE, i was just trying to clarify. Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial written by us, MyFlashLab team that might be useful to you, here's the link http://www.myflashlabs.com/build-multiplayer-games-in-adobe-air-using-bluetooth-ane/ and here are some key points for initializing and adding listeners to the Bluetooth ANE.

```
var _ex:Bluetooth = new Bluetooth();

// dispatches the state of Bluetooth whenever it changes (you will know if it's on or off)
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.BLUETOOTH_STATE , bluetoothState);

// dispatches the communication state of two devices
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.COMMUNICATION_STATUS , communication);

// dispatches the connection state of two devices. Are the devices connected or not.
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.CONNECTION , connection);

// dispatches the 'enable' and 'visibility' dialog states
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.DIALOG_STATUS , dialog);

// dispatches the device discovering state
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.DISCOVERING_STATUS , discovering);

// dispatches when new devices are discovered
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.NEW_DISCOVERD , newDiscoverd);

// dispatches whenever a new String message is received from the other device
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.READ_MESSAGE , readMessage);

// dispatches to notify you about the scan mode of the device
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.SCAN_MODE , scanMode);

// dispatches when a String message is sent to the other device
_ex.addEventListener(BluetoothEvent.SEND_MESSAGE , sendMessage);

// check if Bluetooth hardware is on or off
if (_ex.isEnable)
{
    // make Bluetooth visible to others infinitely 
    // or set a duration which must be between 0 and 3600
    _ex.visible(0);

    // start the communication service for Bluetooth
    _ex.initCommunicationService();
}
else
{
    // if it's not on, just turn it on
    _ex.enable();
}

// listen to know when the Bluetooth is turning on
function bluetoothState(e:BluetoothEvent):void
{
    trace("state >> " + e.param);

    if (e.param == "bluetoothOn")
    {
        // as soon as it's on, make it visible and start the communication service
        _ex.visible(0);
        _ex.initCommunicationService();
    }
}
```